# SQLite method driving me crazy

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm using this method to update a row in my DB:

```
- (void)Update: (int)idMed {    
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
    sqlite3 *dbase;
    NSString *database = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"rtDb.sqlite"];
    sqlite3_open([database UTF8String], &dbase);
    const char *sql = "UPDATE orari SET pr=1 WHERE dataid=?";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbase, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, idMed);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(dbase);
}
```

I've triple checked the data sent to this method, the idMed is correct and if I use the query in my SQLite manager, it works. Actually also this method works, but just a few times. Most of time it does nothing.

The same exact code is used in another method that makes a SELECT and then this same UPDATE and there it works, here not.

UPDATE: It seems I'm getting errors for the STEP and FINALIZE rows.

Comment: You don't check for errors at all, no wonder you're being driven crazy. It always happens, if you don't check.

Comment: You mean check for errors during the row update? How to do it?

Comment: example `int result; result = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, idMed); assert(SQLITE_OK == result);`, but it could be more elaborate. Just insert the asserts everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the problem.
I was reading another table of the same DB in another thread and that was somehow blocking this update method.
I was sure I'd already deleted all the background operations on my DB from my code, but this one escaped my check.

By the way, I'm still getting an error on the STEP row, but it's working anyways.